# How to Unpublish a whole site in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: publishing-site

I have an About Us section and three pages added in this sectino. Now i want to unpublished complete About Us section in SharePoint 2010. Can anybody Please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details about your requirement.

Comment: Hi! You need to add more details about your scenario and what you try to accomplish. As the question is written right now, all answers will be just guesses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feroz,

By unpublishing if you mean that users should not be able to access the subsite, you can remove users permissions from subsite.. This will not actually unpublish but will give users message that they don't have permissions to view this site.

However if you mean to completely REMOVE the subsite, you can use [Remove-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607890.aspx) powershell command to remove the subsites.

For keeping it as a backup you can go to Site Settings -> Save site as template (can include content as well).. You can restore the subsite from backup later!